# Placing an UIImageView using AutoLayout in iOS storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, ios-autolayout

I am very much new to this AutoLayout thing in iOS and I had hard time to find good documentation to read and understand it's concepts.

What I need to do is place a UIImageView inside the parent View in a position related to parent View height.

How I tried to achieve that is as below.

[image]

This works for every screen size but only in portrait. When I rotate the device either left or right I cannot see any change of the gap between UIImageView and the top of the landscaped device. Below image clarify what I meant here.

[image]

But when I see the previews using storyboard it display the gap difference as I expected.

[image]

1.) Why this does not happen when the app runs on a real device?

2.) Do I have to update the constraints programmatically when a device rotation detected?

3.) Is there any constant value for Top Layout Guide.Bottom X and Y ?

4.) Is there any other way to place this UIImageView? What I need is to place the image 1/3 of the position of screen height in any orientation.

Comment: I can answer to point 4, in code, to place an image view with specific frame, but what exactly happens on a real device?

Comment: @BHendricks yes, that way we can add UIImageView. My concern is placing it in the parent View independent of the device orientation. What you suggesting is giving the constraints programmatically too. Isn't it?

Comment: I think that will work with only with size class to success your purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constraint what you need is like below.

[image: image 1]

How you going to give is, selecting the UIImageView and after like below screenshot

[image: image 2]

When you give constraint like in second screenshot you don't get exact values which you can see on first screenshot. You have to manually give the Multiplier value according to your choice.

A tutorial about [iOS AutoLayout with UIImageView](https://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2015/05/22/ios-autolayout-with-a-uiimageview/)